# Elasticsearch helm chart with basic authentication

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

i want to set basic authentication only username:password to ES clutser. i have created kubernetes secret and added in `values.yaml` file also added `xpack.security.enabled: true`.

my web app would be sending request over simple HTTP only.

Please let me know if it is possible just set basic authentication username: credentials without setting up SSL transport layer security.

**UPDATE**

i am done with basic setup, mean basic auth and certificate creation working well also cluster is up.

but when i am sending curl request getting

`curl localhost:9200`

`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

but when sending curl with `--insecure` or with `-k` getting response

```
{
  "name" : "elasticsearch-master-0",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "sUVANxDTQI2L8iSYBXIijg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.3.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "1c1faf1",
    "build_date" : "2019-09-06T14:40:30.409026Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.1.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

any solution of this `--insecure` i think error occurring due to self-sign certificates.

`elasticsearach.yaml file`

```
esConfig:
  elasticsearch.yml: |
    xpack.security.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
    xpack.security.http.ssl.truststore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs/elastic-certificates.p12
    xpack.security.authc.realms.native.local.order: 0
```

Thanks. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Comment any http.ssl strings. You will connect via http not https but your password will be transferred in plain text. Not recommend in prod.

Comment: what will be DNS name when creating certificates ??? currently cluster working with only curl insecure mode.

Comment: not sure understand your question. if you are using "insecure" mode - you can use any dns name. better of course is using an your real name. "server name" + "dot" + "domain suffix". so if you have domain name myhomelab.com and two nodes elk1 and elk2, you should issue certificate with two SANs, elk1.myhomelab.com and elk2.myhomelab.com or wildcard certificate *.myhomelab.com -> so it will cover all new nodes added by you.